# android studio skip rebuilding packages that are not modified

Tags: android, build, task, skip

My project contains multiple modules (or packages).
Lets say that i have packages A, B, C..etc. Each package has its own build.gradle file.

Now when ever i try to build the application it builds all the packages. Even though i only work with one package. It takes almost 3 mins to build all my packages for every single character change.

This is what happening with my PACKAGE A, this thing happens with all my packages

```
:PACKAGE A:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm780Library UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareMYAPPLICATIONDatameterUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareMYAPPLICATIONLib_mvm_commonUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareMYAPPLICATIONLib_vnslibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareMYAPPLICATIONLib_volleyUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareMYAPPLICATIONVzwanalyticsUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:prepareReleaseDependencies
:PACKAGE A:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:PACKAGE A:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
```

Is there any way to tell the gradle that i dont wanna rebuild the packages that im not working with.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the `UP-TO-DATE` message indicate that it is skipping the file since there are no changes?

Comment: @nukeforum im not sure, but i think its a task to make sure that its up to date